# Problem with UV unwrap rotation

Tags: uv

I have modeled a simple folded carton box. When i UV unwrap the mesh i get a rotated UV. Why? Maybe i miss something?
[image]

Comment: Tnx so much! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pin.

1. in uv editor get 2 connected vert and make them aligned on an axis
   then press p to pin the 2 vert.
2. unwrap model
3. un pin with alt + p
4. scale acordingly
   [image]

Comment: "UV Unwrap" will always try to cover the most area possible, so you can expect it to be rotated. However, if you experiment with other methods on a case-by-case basis, you can get (almost exactly what you need in a couple of clicks. Since each face rotat ion offset is a multiple of 90 degrees, I recommend you try Box Projection. If that doesn't look right, I often use Smart UV unwrap, which will automatically align most UV islands with the axes of the canvas. If you have not already learnew about UV seams (identifying the borders of UV islands), you will find everything easier after you learn.